# Change of variables to derive Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Let $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ be a periodic function of period $2L$. Define $$a_n=\dfrac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^Lf(x)e^{-in\pi x/L}dx$$ Show by change of variables that $$f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_ne^{i\pi nx/L}$$

I'm quite confused about what "change of variables" refers to here.

**Edit**: Following *mathematician*'s hint: the sum can be rearranged as

$$\dfrac{1}{2L}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \left(\int_{-L}^Lf(y)e^{in\pi (x-y)/L}dy\right)$$

But what can we do next? How can we get that this above thing is equal to $f(x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty (\frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^L f(y)e^{-in\pi x/L} dy ) e^{i\pi nx/L}$ with the goal of showing this equals $f(x)$.  The use of two different variables is necessary because the $y$ is being "integrated away" to get the constant $a_n$.  Change of variables may be used once you move the infinite sum and $e^{i\pi nx/L}$ inside the integral (which you can do by linearity plus some convergence theorem e.g. the dominated cvgce theorem).

Comment: I can't see how this is related to the dominated convergence theorem. Would you please elaborate some more?

Comment: Now that I look at it it's more complicated than I thought..  You're right, the dominated convergence theorem doesn't apply.  I'm not aware of an easy way to show pointwise convergence of Fourier series for smooth functions.